# Problem in using tab bar controller with navigation controller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a navigation based application. I am using navigation controller for this purpose. I want to use tab bar on one of the screens and i am not able to find any way of doing this. As far as i have read, it is not possible to add tab bar controller when you are using navigation controller. Is it right? One solution was to manually add a tab bar on the screen and write its delegate class but in this solution, I will lose "More" button functionality because this thing is handled by tab bar controller itself. Does anyone has any solution to my problem? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UINavigationController` to each of the `UITabBarController`'s tab views but not the other way around.

According to Apple's documentation you cannot push a `UITabBarController` on top of the `UINavigationController`. I'm not sure if that is a technical limitation or if they will reject your application when you submit. Either way you shouldn't try to do this.

Comment: Ok i understand. Is there any other way of acheiving what i want to do? Any suggestions for how to change my architecture?